# How do i split a table for responsive using css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to split a table columns as per attachment image using CSS/jquery. You can find HTML code at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jcx0rcb9/29/), also I am using below HTML table structure for desktop and I am trying to make it responsive as per attachment image:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Main Title 1</th>
      <th>Main Title 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sub-title">
      <td colspan="2">Sub Title 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1.1</td>
      <td>Content 1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub-title">
      <td colspan="2">Sub Title 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 2.1</td>
      <td>Content 2.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Make two separate tables and show/hide each other respectively

Comment: Try to use bootstrap toolkit http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Yes, I am using bootstrap. @WaelAbbas

Comment: Yes, i have tried to make it separate but it's not get success. because it's creating problem equal height of row in desktop view. @pokeybit

Comment: use somthing elese than table

Answer (score 0):

> A responsive table will display a horizontal scroll bar if the screen
> is too small to display the full content

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive-sm">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Main Title 1</th>
        <th>Main Title 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Sub Title 1</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content 1.1</td>
        <td>Content 1.2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Sub Title 2</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content 2.1</td>
        <td>Content 2.2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

To achieve your goal you need to use [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

> Bootstrap's grid system is responsive, and the columns will re-arrange
> depending on the screen size: On a big screen it might look better
> with the content organized in three columns, but on a small screen it
> would be better if the content items were stacked on top of each
> other.

Comment: I have used bootstrap table but the problem i don't need scroll bar in responsive screen, i just want to split right column to bottom as per previous attachment image.